# Disable/deny going back to previous page on asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On my current project I want to deny going back once my customers hit submit button and redirected to the final page. How can I deny from going back to previous page or some mechanism to expire the page if the back button is clicked. I tried this code and it didn't work

page.response.cache.setcacheability(httpcacheability.nocache)

Comment: I am waiting to see the answer for the same question a long ago.

Comment: Duplicate. This is a javascript question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947322/how-to-disable-back-button-of-browser-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    history.forward();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form runat="server" id="form1">
<%
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Expires = 0
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
%>
```

I put this in my master page and it works great!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Place the following between the `<head> </head>` of ALL your pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        history.forward();
</script>
```

And check this article out:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml

Comment: @ysrb  I'm using master page....I put it like this and didst work...<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Thankyou.aspx.vb" Inherits="Thankyou" MasterPageFile="~/SurveyMasterPage.master" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    history.forward();
</script>

Comment: @MIlla Can you put it inside the MasterPage? It needs to be inside `<head>` tags

Comment: that couldn't resolve it...I c this code on forums and this also didn't solve it    Response.Buffer= true;
Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires =-1500;
Response.CacheControl = “no-cache”;

// Check for your SessionID
if(Session["SessionId"] == null)
{
  Response.Redirect (”Home.aspx”);
}

Comment: @Mllla Which browser are you testing?

Comment: @Mllla , can you please share which methods suit you?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, use this Java script function, its 100% working fine, would not let you go back.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```