# How to disable back button of browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to disable the back buttons in the browser using JavaScript. Can any one help me how to do that?

Comment: You can't. If you think you need to, then you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: The title of this question could also be "How to make my visitors really angry" :-)

Comment: Would you like to arrive on a website and you notice you cannot use the back button to go back? Think about it...

Comment: Open your website in new window with out menubar and lock key backspace and alt + <- ....

Comment: @cloberink — right click, pick Back from context menu.

Comment: Maybe I too am solving the wrong problem, but I also think I need to disable navigation buttons temporarily.  My front end uses JQuery AJAX/JSON to retrieve data from a server to populate portions of the page.  I noticed that if I hit the back button during an AJAX request, the browser (Chrome in my case) goes into a bad state (the updating indicator circle keeps rotating and back/forward buttons no longer respond to input).  I thought I could resolve this by disabling the buttons during a request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read here for [several options to disable the back button](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript).

BUT: The question makes me feel like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

The back button is something that the user expects to work. If you disable it, you would break the browser (from the user perspective): Something that works everywhere else doesn't work on your page. Users would hate your page and try to avoid it. If they can't avoid the page, they would hate it even more.

So what are your options:

1. You can get events when the user uses the button. GWT, for example, saves the internal state of the application in virtual history events. So the user can use the back button like Undo in a real application.
2. Avoid creating history events for your page. Make sure the URL in the title bar never changes. Save all changes on your server. For the user, the page/application will feel like one page. When he returns next time, restore the last state from the database on your server.

   This way, the user can use the back button to leave your page as he is used to but he still won't loose any work.
3. A mix of the two. For example stack overflow allows you to move between the pages using links and the back button. If you start to edit something on a page, you get a warning when you click on the back button.

Answer (score 1):

```
function noBack() {
    window.history.forward();
}
```

Comment: Oh look. My back button has an arrow beside it that lets me skip two pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Simple logic: move forward when click back button
 ---------------------------------------------------- 

function preventBack() {
    window.history.forward();
}
 window.onunload = function() {
    null;
};
setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);


Keep this js code in your page it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply open your page in a new tab using javascript like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">window.open('yourpage.html');</script>
```

set this code to your previous page and this will open your page in a new tab and there will be no back button available.

Comment: I think the OP wants to disable them for the entire site. Your solution won't work for subsequent page loads.