# How to disable the Backspace button in Internet explorer using asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, caching

Currently when i press the backspace button after logout then the previous page opens instead to redirect it to login page , I  used this server side code in page load of my logout page and it works with firefox, opera and chrome but for IE and Safari it is not working fine.

here is my code in page load of log-out page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Session.Abandon();
            Session.Clear();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();  
    }
```

what you suggest for this to work on both IE and Safari ?

Comment: There are several options for disabling the back button. You may try following solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947322/how-to-disable-back-button-of-browser-using-javascript http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/

Comment: there is No 100% way of doing it, there will always be a way to go back. You have to think of a different approach. Like if Session Content is CLEAR then force redirect to some another page.

Comment: @highwingers i have redirect page to login page after session empty but when i press backspace it does not go to page load but redirects to previous page...

Answer (score 2):

I think even if disable the back button, the user can go back by pressing "Alt + arrow button" or "backspace". Disabling back button is not possible in browsers.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1.**

*Add the below javascript code on the page load*

```
    <script>
     function callme()
     {
        history.go(1);  
     }
    </script>
```

**Step 2.**

*Dont allow the page to be saved in cache. Add the below lines between* < head > section

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">

<meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

**Step 3.**

*On click of Logout. Clear the history from the browser and redirects to Login page from server side.*

```
 string strScript = "<script>var Backlen=history.length;history.go(-Backlen);window.location.replace('Login.aspx');</script>";




ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ClearHistory", strScript);
```

**Edit:**

- You can use Step 2 and 3 in combination
- Or Step 1 and 2
- Or all three
- All three steps are recommended

Comment: these are 3 different solution in steps or these 3 steps are interlinked?\

Comment: Really? Delete someone's history?

Answer (score -1):

in you body tag of master page or any aspx page

add this tag

```
<body  onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();">
```

in java script

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        noBack();
    }
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
</script>
```

It will definetly not allowed user to go to previous page